# calibre opds error 403 on the epub file

Tags: apache-httpd, calibre

I'm trying to use calibre2opds to put my library on my server (fedora21). Everything works fine, I can navigate, until I want to download an epub.

I get en error 403:

```
You don't have permission to access /Anonyme/Le Livre Sans Nom (41)/Le Livre Sans Nom - Anonyme.epub on this server.
```

I access the server by 192.168.1.21/calibre. Calibre2ops put everything in

```
/mnt/Sardaukar/web/calibre
```

The HTML files are put by calibre2opds in

```
/mnt/Sardaukar/web/calibre/_catalog
```

and the actual epubs in, for instance

```
/mnt/Sardaukar/web/calibre/Anonyme/Le Livre Sans Nom (41)/Le Livre Sans Nom - Anonyme.epub
```

and the httpd file looks like

```
Alias /calibre /mnt/Sardaukar/web/calibre/_catalog
<Directory /mnt/Sardaukar/web/calibre/_catalog>
AllowOverride All
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I did it before, even with an .htaccess and it worked before, but now, I have no idea what is wrong. The permissions on /mnt/Sardaukar/web/calibre are 770, and chown by me:www-users

After more research, I found in the error log:

```
[Mon Jun 22 21:06:59.774348 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 10805] [client 192.168.1.5:51992] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/Anonyme, referer: http://192.168.1.21/calibre/book_0
 >>>/book_41.html
```

Why does it try to read the epub in `/var/www/html`??

Comment: Read your error again: `/Anonyme/Le Livre Sans Nom (41)/Le Livre Sans Nom - Anonyme.epub on this server.`  Your entire path must be owned by `www-user` not just your alias.  Try `chown -Rv  www-user:www-user /Anonyme`

Comment: hi. This doesn't change anything, I chown apache:www-users the whole /mnt/Sardaukar/web/calibre . It seems logical, since the permissions are already 770. (and 777 doesn't change this behavior)

Comment: Would you please verify the owner of at least one epub file in the `Le Livre Sans Nom (41)` directory?

Comment: Yes, here it is:
    -rwxr--r-- 1 napseis www-users 1,2M 21 juin  21:29 /mnt/Sardaukar/web/calibre/Anonyme/Le Livre Sans Nom (41)/Le Livre Sans Nom - Anonyme.epub

Comment: As I suspected `napseis` is not `www-users`.  You need to either rerun the command I gave above, so that the owner is `www-users` along with the group `www-users` or to shorcut, you can add the user `napseis` to the group `www-users`.  On a side note, make sure the `www-users` user exist.  There is a typo in my original command.  Be sure to add an s to the end of both sets of `user`.

Comment: the `www-users` does not exists, only the group. Apache is run by the user `apache`. I did try to run the chown with apache:www-users, and even did a chmod 777. This doesn't chaneg anything. I more likely suspect something wrong in the conf files inside `/etc/httpd`

Comment: Try adding user `napseis` to group `www-users`... If that doesn't work, undo the assignment, then poke around in Apache

Comment: napseis is in the group. I looked into the error log, and updated the main post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, see the [DistrosDefaultLayout - Fedora](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout#Fedora_Core.2C_CentOS.2C_RHEL:) entry on the Apache Wiki

Looks like you may need to add a Document Root (to override the default), and since you aren't serving files from the default root, a ServerRoot (again to override the default):

```
Alias /calibre /mnt/Sardaukar/web/calibre/_catalog
ServerRoot "/calibre"
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Anonyme/"
    ServerName mypubs.local

# Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /mnt/Sardaukar/web/calibre/_catalog>
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This should make the Entire path read {ServerRoot} + {DocumentRoot}, or {Alias /calibre} + Anonyme

### Reasoning

For Security Reasons, Apache does not allow directory traversal outside the `ServerRoot`.  Your link to all your books wasn't a valid path in `ServerRoot`.  Therefore, I had to tell Apache where your server was being "served"  If none of this makes sense Read [this great in-depth article over on Slicehost](http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/12/3/apache-virtual-hosts-on-gentoo-part-1).  Since Gentoo isn't your distribution use the **Linux Distros** Link in the Navigation to find the same article I linked for your particular distribution.  As a matter of learning and practice, I would keep your epubs in a safe place, and do the following:

1. Delete my hackish `httpd.conf` file.
2. Follow the guide I linked to enable/configure Virtual Hosting Properly.
3. Add your epubs to the VirtualHost Configuration you created in Step #2.

Comment: Thank you, the conf file your provided wasn't correct, but your explanations helped me a lot, and now it works !

Comment: @Napseis Great!!  If you like, would you provide your fixed conf file, either in your question or here...